# Installing Composer on CentOS with multiple PHP versions

Tags: centos

I have multiple versions of PHP (5.6 and 7.2) installed on my CentOS 7 server.

Googling CentOS 7 Composer installation seems to have the same guide, just under a different blog with these steps:

```
$ curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
$ mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
$ chmod +x /usr/local/bin/composer
$ composer -V    
Composer version 1.5.2 2017-09-11 16:59:25
```

However, this threw an error straight away. So I changed this command:

```
$ curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
```

to:

```
$ curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php72
```

This now downloaded the file, however when I tried using composer -V (after the other steps) it throws this error:

> /usr/bin/env: php: No such file or directory

So I vim'd into `/usr/local/bin/composer` to see the line right at the top:

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
```

I changed that to

```
#!/usr/bin/env php72
```

but doing `composer -V` now shows:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught PharException: phar "/usr/local/bin/composer" has a broken signature in /usr/local/bin/composer:23
Stack trace:
#0 /usr/local/bin/composer(23): Phar::mapPhar('composer.phar')
#1 {main}
  thrown in /usr/local/bin/composer on line 23
```

I tried the same with php56 to the same result.

How do I go about installing composer correctly on a CentOS 7 server running multiple versions of PHP?

Sidenote: lemme know if this is better for say ... superuser

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on the version of php you would like to use.
Could you please show us the error you get when you try to install composer with php56 ?

Anyways "php" is just a symlink to the real php binary, wich in your case seems to be pointing to php 56, to make sure of that do a ls -l on the symlink, that you can locate by typing

```
whereis php
```

So if you want the full chain to be php72, replace that symlink with a new one that will point to the php72 binary.
Or perhaps you can use an alias :

```
alias php="/path/to/php72"
```

Comment: the exact same^^ however I did find a solution after making the question! and it pretty much is the alias fix you have above^^

Answer (score 0):

My overall solution was to do this:

1. Create an alias in `~/.bashrc`: `alias php="php72"`
2. Then install composer with above steps without any amedments
3. Then go back into `~/.bashrc` to add a new alias: `alias composer_72="php /usr/local/bin/composer"`

Now I have composer working on `PHP7.2`